# XSLT on itunes Library

Tags: xml, xslt, itunes

I need to extract the Track ID and Location from an itunes library.xml file.
I have found some XSLT solution but they are all XSLT Version 2.0 based.

I am limited to XSLT Version 1.0 .

Can anybody help how to do this .

Output should be:

```
98,location---
100,location 2
```

many thanks for the help 
 Matthias

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
      <key>Tracks</key>
      <dict>
         <key>98</key>
         <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key>
            <integer>98</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>xxxxxx</string>
            <key>Location</key>
            <string>location---</string>
         </dict>
         <key>100</key>
         <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key>
            <integer>100</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>name2</string>
            <key>Location</key>
            <string>location 2</string>
         </dict>
      </dict>
   </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Did you try writing any code? Did you try converting the XSLT2.0 to 1.0 and seeing what heppened - many XSLT2.0 commands are backwards compatible?

Answer (score 2):

So for each `key` in the Tracks `dict` you want to extract the `Location`.  How about this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="plist/dict/dict/key" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="key">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <!-- find the dict corresponding to this key, and extract the value of
         the Location entry -->
    <xsl:value-of select="
       following-sibling::dict[1]/key[. = 'Location']/following-sibling::string[1]" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the plist consistently puts Location as the last entry then you could simply say

```
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict[1]/string[last()]" />
```

but doing it by finding the right key value and then taking its first following `string` is more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Change the XSLT version number in the file header to 1.0. I can't imagine output this simple requires anything not supported by 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming correct input (one more closing `</dict>`), you could use the following Stylesheet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="text" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="plist">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="dict[parent::plist]">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="key[.='Tracks']/dict">
      <xsl:for-each select="descendant::dict">
         <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::key" />
         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="descendant::key[.='Location']/following-sibling::string" />
         <xsl:text />
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="key|string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Name']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT** @Ian Yes, you're right of course. I have altered my remark.

Note that you have to rely on navigating the document tree with e.g. `following-sibling` because of the shallow hierarchy of the XML file.

Comment: The XML may be ugly but it's the standard XML serialization of the "property list" format that's used for hundreds of different purposes all over Mac OS X and iOS.  In spirit it's more like JSON - a `dict` is a mapping from string keys to values that can be string, boolean, numeric, another `dict`, or an array of any of the above.  Sometimes plists are stored using XML serialization, sometimes they're stored in a binary format.